# Using Microsoft Graph with javascript, Application not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I want to use the Microsoft Graph API with javascript.I am following the below tutorial:

[Microsoft Graph Javascript Tutorial Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript)

I have created the demo app following the above link. Application is working fine in Edge and Chrome browser but it is not working in IE 11.
In IE 11, I am getting below error in my code:

IE Browser Error Screen shot:

[image]

IE is giving error in below line of code:

**const graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider});**

[image]

I need to fix the line of code, which is not working in IE 11 :

**const graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider});**

Answer (score 0):

That line uses an es6 feature for a shorthand assignment of properties in objects. Unfortunately, IE doesn't support es6 so you will probably need to either rewrite this to something like:

```
const graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider: authProvider});
```

or use a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)